# TypeScript - how to define a type inside a tuple based on the combination of a generic + another value of the tuple? (like tuple[1]: T[tuple[0]])

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, typescript-generics

As the title goes: how to define a type, based on the combination of a generic + another value, in a tuple, like `tuple[1]: T[tuple[0]]`?

**Context:**

I'm using a tuple to store different values, in order to then create a table.

I have an array of rows of a certain type (ex. `MyDataDTO`) that holds all the different properties of a row.

The tuple defines a single column of the table. The full table definition will be an array of these tuples.

The tuple has 2 values:

[0] -> field of the column, can only be one of the keys of `MyDataDTO` (no issues here)

[1] -> a function that accepts the value of the cell as parameter (here is the problem) and renders it.

**This is what I tried:**

```
type ColumnDefinitionTuple<TRowData> = {
    [K in keyof TRowData]: [K, (cellValue: TRowData[K]) => string];
}[keyof TRowData];

type MyDataDTO = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    code: number;
};

const tableData: MyDataDTO[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "test-1", code: 101 },
    { id: 2, name: "test-2", code: 102 },
    { id: 3, name: "test-3", code: 103 },
];

const tableColumnsDefinition: ColumnDefinitionTuple<MyDataDTO> = [
    "id", // OK -> works with type-safety and autocomplete
    (value) => "", // NOT OK -> the "value" parameter is typed as "any", it should be typed as "number" because MyDataDTO["id"] (TRowData[K]) is a number
];
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just change data structure. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/WG4dVw)